# TFlearn evaluate method results meaning

Tags: tensorflow

I thought that TFlearn's `evaluate` method returns the accuracy of the model (0 to 1) but after training my model `model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)` returns a value > 1 (1.003626), so now I'm not sure I understand exactly what it returns.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

The evaluate method returns a dict, so the call would be

`model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)['accuracy']`

but I'm guessing that's not the problem. If you are doing classification, the test labels have to be integers for this to work. Other than that, without seeing more of your code, it's hard to debug.

Comments from the source code for evaluate:

`Args:
      x: Matrix of shape [n_samples, n_features...] or dictionary of many matrices
         containing the input samples for fitting the model. Can be iterator that returns
         arrays of features or dictionary of array of features. If set,`input_fn`must
         be`None`.
      y: Vector or matrix [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs] containing the
         label values (class labels in classification, real numbers in
         regression) or dictionary of multiple vectors/matrices. Can be iterator
         that returns array of targets or dictionary of array of targets. If set,
         input_fn must be`None`. Note: For classification, label values must
         be integers representing the class index (i.e. values from 0 to
         n_classes-1).`